Rust iterator iterate until the first element where the condition is not held
Given a Vec<i32> I'd like to create a Vec<i32> containing all first i32s with a predicate returning true dropping all elements once the first element not satisfying the predicate is encountered. The simple filter implementation as
fn first_predicate<F>(vec: Vec<i32>, f: F) -> Vec<i32>
where
    F: FnMut(&i32) -> bool,
{
    vec.into_iter().filter(f).collect() //return all elements satisfying the predicate, not the first group
}

as it returns all the elements satisfying the predicate.
Is there a way to stop iteration once an element not satisfying the predicate is encountered?

Yes, you can use take_while instead of filter.

You can use Vec::retain, to do this in-place and avoid unnecessary allocations.
fn first_predicate<T, F>(vec: &mut Vec<T>, mut predicate: F)
where
    F: FnMut(&T) -> bool,
{
    let mut passed = true;
    vec.retain(|x| {
        if !passed {
            return false;
        }
        
        passed = predicate(x);
        passed
    })
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let mut data = vec![2, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2];
    let is_even = |x: &i32| *x % 2 == 0;
    first_predicate(&mut data, is_even);
    assert_eq!(&data, &[2, 4]);
}

This of course will require to iterate over all elements of the original vector. So if you have a large number of elements, and predicate returns false early, you still have to go through all of them, which can be slow (although the branch predictor should have easy job here).

You can't use retain to "stop iteration once an element not satisfying the predicate is encountered".

I know. You visit in-place the whole vector. But on the other hand you don't need to allocate a new one. Just wanted to show a different solution with different trade-off. Because functionally, this does what OP asked about.
